# How do I decide when to mark a function as unsafe?

Tags: rust

When is it appropriate to mark a function as `unsafe` versus just using an `unsafe` block? I saw this function while reading [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042896/155423):

```
unsafe fn as_u8_slice(xs: &[i32]) -> &[u8] {
    std::slice::from_raw_parts(v.as_ptr() as *const u8, 
                               v.len() * std::mem::size_of::<i32>())
}
```

I probably would have written the function as:

```
fn as_u8_slice(xs: &[i32]) -> &[u8] {
    unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(v.as_ptr() as *const u8, 
                                   v.len() * std::mem::size_of::<i32>())
    }
}
```

That is, I feel like *calling the function* is safe in all cases, but what the function does *internally* cannot be verified by the compiler. However, I don't have any rules for when it is appropriate to use one or the other.

Comment: that fact that "calling the function is safe in all cases" should be the precise criterion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mark a function as `unsafe` iff the function's safety depends on its parameters or on global state. If the function is safe regardless of arguments and global state, don't mark it as `unsafe`. Whether you consider a function that uses `unsafe` internally safe is the same as whether you consider a C program safe.

Answer (score 5):

`unsafe` is designed as a local mechanism to step around the type system when the compiler is unable to prove safety. If the behaviour encapsulated by the `unsafe` is safe, i.e. there is no way to call it that will cause memory unsafety, then there is no need to label the overall function unsafe. The user doesn't need to care if the function internals are implemented entirely with safe code or with `unsafe`, as long as the exposed interface is correct.