# When is it appropriate to mark a trait as unsafe, as opposed to marking all the functions in the trait as unsafe?

Tags: rust, traits

Saying the same thing in code, when would I pick either of the following examples?

```
unsafe trait MyCoolTrait {
    fn method(&self) -> u8;
}

trait MyCoolTrait {
    unsafe fn method(&self) -> u8;
}
```

The [opt-in builtin traits (OIBIT) RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md) states:

> An unsafe trait is a trait that is unsafe to implement, because it represents some kind of trusted assertion. Note that unsafe traits are perfectly safe to use. [`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and `Share` (*note: now called [`Sync`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html)*) are examples of unsafe traits: implementing these traits is effectively an assertion that your type is safe for threading.

There's another example of an unsafe trait in the standard library, [`Searcher`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Searcher.html). It says:

> The trait is marked unsafe because the indices returned by the `next()` methods are required to lie on valid utf8 boundaries in the haystack. This enables consumers of this trait to slice the haystack without additional runtime checks.

Unfortunately, neither of these paragraphs really help my understanding of when it is correct to mark the entire trait unsafe instead of some or all of the methods.

[I've asked about marking a function as unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050360/155423) before, but this seems different.

Comment: not sure how to put this into a good answer b/c it seems to obvious to me. Unsafe traits only have a use for safe code. You mark a trait as unsafe when you want the implementor to pay additional attention when implementing the trait, because it's easy to get wrong AND any implementors are basically guaranteed to need unsafe code to implement that trait.

Comment: @ker  `Send` and `Sync` don't even have any methods that the implementer could need `unsafe` for, nor do the methods of `Searcher` seem `unsafe`-requiring to me. And `unsafe` is *never* about "easy to get wrong", only about memory safety.

Comment: send and sync are marker traits. I don't think this question is about marker traits. unsafe is always about "easy to get wrong" (+ causing memory unsafety). if the implementor has to type unsafe, he knows he might be causing memory unsafety if he doesn't fully know what he's doing even if he's writing safe code. in case of unsafe functions in unsafe traits, the implementation needs to make guarantees AND the caller, in case of unsafe traits only the implementor needs to make guarantees. The confusion exists because a safe free function can't be overloaded.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A function is marked `unsafe` to indicate that it is possible to violate memory safety by calling it.  A trait is marked `unsafe` to indicate that it is possible to violate memory safety by implementing it *at all*.  This is commonly because the trait has invariants that other unsafe code relies on being upheld, and that these invariants *cannot* be expressed any other way.

In the case of `Searcher`, the methods themselves *should* be safe to call.  That is, *users* should not have to worry about whether or not they're using a `Searcher` correctly; the interface contract says all calls are safe.  There's nothing you can do that will cause the methods to violate memory safety.

*However*, unsafe code will be calling the methods of a `Searcher`, and such unsafe code will be *relying* on a given `Searcher` implementation to return offsets that are on valid UTF-8 code point boundaries.  If this assumption is violated, then the unsafe code could end up causing a memory safety violation itself.

To put it another way: the correctness of unsafe code using `Searcher`s *depends* on every single `Searcher` implementation *also* being correct.  Or: implementing this trait incorrectly allows for safe code to *induce* a memory safety violation is unrelated `unsafe` code.

So why not just mark the methods `unsafe`?  Because they *aren't* unsafe at all!  They don't *do* anything that could violate memory safety in and of themselves.  `next_match` just scans for and returns an `Option<(usize, usize)>`.  The danger only exists when unsafe code *assumes* that these `usize`s are valid indices into the string being searched.

So why not just *check* the result?  Because that'd be slower.  The searching code wants to be *fast*, which means it wants to avoid redundant checks.  But those checks can't be expressed in the `Searcher` interface... so instead, the whole trait is flagged as `unsafe` to warn anyone implementing it that there are extra conditions *not* stated or enforced in the code that *must* be respected.

There's also `Send` and `Sync`: implementing those when you shouldn't violates the expectations of (among other things) code that has to deal with threads.  The code that lets you create threads is safe, but *only* so long as `Send` and `Sync` are *only* implemented on types for which they're appropriate.

Comment: Since an unsafe trait and unsafe functions in a trait are orthogonal, can you think of any cases where you might have both?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I can't think of a *practical* example, but it's certainly not impossible to envisage an unsafe trait where a subset of its methods have an unsafe interface.  Perhaps a marker trait (like `Send` or `Sync`) where you have unsafe code relying on the marker trait which *also* exposes a method dealing in raw pointers (which would thus be unsafe to *call*).

Comment: Ok, cool. In my particular interface I have a trait that accepts raw pointers and returns UTF-8 offsets into a string, so I think I might just qualify for double unsafety. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb will be like this:

- Use `unsafe fn method()` if the method user need to wrap method call in `unsafe` block.
- Use `unsafe trait MyTrait` if the trait implementor need to `unsafe impl MyTrait`.

`unsafe` is a tip to Rust user: unsafe code must be written carefully. 
The key point is that `unsafe` should be used as dual: when an author declare a trait/function as unsafe, the implementor/user need to implement/use it with `unsafe`.

When function is marked as `unsafe`, it means the user needs to use the function carefully. The function author is making assumption that the function user must keep.

When trait is marked as `unsafe`, it means the trait implementor needs to implement carefully. The trait requires implementor keeps certain assumption. But users of the unsafe trait can insouciantly call methods defined in the trait.

For concrete example, `unsafe trait Searcher` requires all `Searcher` implementation should return valid utf8 boundary when calling `next`. And all implementation are marked as `unsafe impl Searcher`, indicating implementation code might be unsafe. But as a user of `Searcher`, one can call `searcher.next()` without wrapping it in `unsafe` block.