# Can I do template specialisation with concrete types in rust?

Tags: templates, generics, rust, template-specialization

I am a beginner in rust, but used to do C++. One thing that you can do in C++ is template specialisation, e.g.

```
// A generic sort function
template <class T>
void sort(T arr[], int size)
{
    // code to implement Quick Sort
}
 
// Template Specialization: A function specialized for char data type
template <>
void sort<char>(char arr[], int size)
{
    // code to implement counting sort
}
```

(see [blogpost](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-specialization-c/)).

In the above example Quick sort is selected as a default implementation, but counting sort is picked if we want to sort chars.

I played around with Rust, but could not get this to work

```
fn test<T: std::fmt::Display>(arg: T) {
    println!("T implements Displai trait '{}'", arg)
}

fn test<T>(arg: T) {
    println!("default version called")
}
```

This gives `the name test is defined multiple times`.

In Rust, can I create generic functions that pick their implementation based on the type of the argument? If so, can I do this with concrete types, like in C++?

The only similar thing I could find was this post, working with traits, not with concrete types ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135833/specialize-method-for-one-specific-generic-type))

**Edit**

```
struct Mytype<T> {
    val: T,
}

impl<T> Mytype<T> {
    fn test(&self) {
        println!("any type T")
    }
}
impl Mytype<f64> {
    fn test2(&self) {
        println!("called with f64")
    }
}

fn main() {
    Mytype { val: "" }.test();
    Mytype { val: 1.0 }.test();
    Mytype { val: 1.0 }.test2();
}
```

In the above example I have a specialised method based on the template type. Here `test2` is only available if you use a `f64`. HOWEVER I still need two different function names, which is not what I want.

Comment: I think this boils down to Rust not having support for overload-able functions, so I'm guessing you'll need to use traits in some form or another.

Comment: In Rust, you can't have the same function defined twice, or the same trait implemented twice, after monomorphisation (that is, replacing generics with concrete types). For this reason, you can implement several functions with the same name for a given time only if, for any concrete value, only one could be picked. This rules out the possibility of having a blanket implementation `impl<T> Mytype<T> { fn test(&self) { ... } }` and a concrete implementation `impl Mytype<f64> { fn test(&self) { ... } }`.

Comment: Specialization is not a stable feature of Rust at this time. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844

Comment: Trust me, many people want this feature, but at the current time it's not 100% clear if it will be possible to introduce it in a sound way. If I remember correctly.

Comment: This blog post is about how C++ specialization compares to what Rust offers instead: https://www.tangramvision.com/blog/c-rust-generics-and-specialization

Comment: @Finomnis It is possible, but IIRC it will require rebuilding some very complex parts of the compiler. Basically, the part of the compiler that type-checks everything can't communicate which specialization is used where to the part of the compiler that actually writes out the code, and the two parts often disagree about which specialization should be used, so you get broken things like a value being treated as a different type than it actually is.

Comment: @cdhowie When we get to a point they disagree this is already bad state since it's specializing on lifetimes. The work on specialization has been stalled for years, probably until something like a-mir-formality can mathematically prove our design is sound. This feature is just too subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All forms of specialisations are not currently supported on stable rust. They are, however, planned and in the process of being implemented [(tracking issue)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844).

An extremely limited subset of the planned features are available on nightly using `#![feature(min_specialization)]`.

As an example, [specialising on simple trait bounds](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9cc7fafa8267663ef3a5cdeb649237af) is currently rejected and [specialising on a specific type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9995163305bbfad0cb87c4b9af87daa6) is also rejected, even when `#![feature(min_specialization)]` is in use.

**Note, as a word of caution,** don't try and use the `#![feature(specialization)]` feature if suggested, as it is currently buggy and unsound, with the potential to give undefined behaviour when used.

Comment: [Specialization on concrete type _is_ allowed with `min_specialization`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a459c59603d9a9d33593ff0f199d18d7) (in fact, it's the place where it is most persmissive, even though still not everything is allowed). You just misplaced the `default`: `default` on the impl (partially specializing an `impl`) is only supported with the full specialization feature, you should put the `default` on the methods.