# How can I write hex-numbers instead of &[u8] to a file

Tags: rust, hex, file-writing

The standard write_all and write functions from the std::fs crate allow to write string slices (so technically &[u8]?) to files.

Is there a way to write hex-numbers directly to the file?

Comment: How are you representing the hex numbers? As strings?

Comment: @SCappella as number literal e.g. 0xff

Comment: That means that this reduces to writing slices of numeric types other than `u8` to files (unless all your hex numbers are less than 256, in which case you can just put them in a `&[u8]` and write that). For that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838358/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-vecu16-content-to-a-file). Two implementations: [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7af590520838b055887f668fad9e9982) or [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cfc4398b13b74d84d533b44045b8676).

Comment: Why don't you post an input example as well as your desired output. To me, it seems like you want to do the following: `format!("0x{:0>2X}", 15) -> "0x0F"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
use std::io::{Result, BufWriter, Write};

fn write_hex<W: Write>(file: &mut BufWriter<W>, data: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
    for val in data {
        write!(file, "{:02X}", val)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bdd426b598d19ffa6c7ec0ab4503e1c)

Since it writes each hex number individually, it requires that you use a buffered stream. You can create one with `BufWriter::new(file)`. You can change `{:02X}` to `{:02x}` to write lower case hex instead.

Comment: A little functional touch if needed : [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=843f489db6a90b9f7052e36ab62b23b3), also doc advises to flush `BufWriter` before it is dropped.