# Converting a Vec<u32> to Vec<u8> in-place and with minimal overhead

Tags: casting, rust, unsafe

I'm trying to convert a `Vec` of `u32`s to a `Vec` of `u8`s, preferably in-place and without too much overhead.

My current solution relies on unsafe code to re-construct the `Vec`. Is there a better way to do this, and what are the risks associated with my solution?

```
use std::mem;
use std::vec::Vec;

fn main() {
    let mut vec32 = vec![1u32, 2];
    let vec8;
    unsafe {
        let length = vec32.len() * 4; // size of u8 = 4 * size of u32
        let capacity = vec32.capacity() * 4; // ^
        let mutptr = vec32.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
        mem::forget(vec32); // don't run the destructor for vec32

        // construct new vec
        vec8 = Vec::from_raw_parts(mutptr, length, capacity);
    }

    println!("{:?}", vec8)
}
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=16096c9762610f92e9ff232da9ef841c&version=stable)

Comment: This is platform dependent, since you don't take the [byteorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) into account.

Comment: https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.2.2/byteorder/trait.ByteOrder.html#tymethod.from_slice_u32 can be used to account for byte order, without copying and is a no-op when the source byte order is the same as the host byte order. Otherwise, I believe your code is safe. Note that the reverse isn't necessarily safe! (Because of alignment.)

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187013/base64-string-↔-float-array/187077

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Whenever writing an `unsafe` block, I *strongly* encourage people to include a comment on the block explaining *why you think the code is actually safe*. That type of information is useful for the people who read the code in the future.
2. Instead of adding comments about the "magic number" 4, just use `mem::size_of::<u32>`. I'd even go so far as to use `size_of` for `u8` and perform the division for maximum clarity.
3. You can return the newly-created Vec from the `unsafe` block.
4. As mentioned in the comments, "dumping" a block of data like this makes the data format *platform dependent*; you will get different answers on little endian and big endian systems. This can lead to massive debugging headaches in the future. File formats either encode the platform endianness into the file (making the reader's job harder) or only write a specific endinanness to the file (making the writer's job harder).
5. I'd probably move the whole `unsafe` block to a function and give it a name, just for organization purposes.
6. You don't need to import `Vec`, it's in the prelude.

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut vec32 = vec![1u32, 2];

    // I copy-pasted this code from StackOverflow without reading the answer 
    // surrounding it that told me to write a comment explaining why this code 
    // is actually safe for my own use case.
    let vec8 = unsafe {
        let ratio = mem::size_of::<u32>() / mem::size_of::<u8>();

        let length = vec32.len() * ratio;
        let capacity = vec32.capacity() * ratio;
        let ptr = vec32.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;

        // Don't run the destructor for vec32
        mem::forget(vec32);

        // Construct new Vec
        Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, length, capacity)
    };

    println!("{:?}", vec8)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=57d8a8c93f81595c5976b0917b93098c&version=stable)

My biggest unknown worry about this code lies in the alignment of the memory associated with the `Vec`.

Rust's underlying allocator [allocates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Alloc.html#tymethod.alloc) and [deallocates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Alloc.html#tymethod.dealloc) memory with *a specific [`Layout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Layout.html)*. `Layout` contains such information as the *size* and *alignment* of the pointer.

I'd assume that this code needs the `Layout` to match between paired calls to `alloc` and `dealloc`. If that's the case, [dropping the `Vec<u8>` constructed from a `Vec<u32>` might tell the allocator the wrong alignment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L680-L698) since that information is [based on the element type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L224-L236).

Without better knowledge, the "best" thing to do would be to leave the `Vec<u32>` as-is and simply get a `&[u8]` to it. The slice has no interaction with the allocator, avoiding this problem.

Even without interacting with the allocator, you need to be careful about alignment!

See also:

- [How to slice a large Vec<i32> as &[u8]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29037033/155423)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309116/155423

Comment: And I'm not sure that `size_of::<u32>() / size_of::<u8>()` is much better than `4`. You have to know the sizes of those types in order to know there won't be any rounding errors. It would be better to multiply by `size_of::<u32>() ` and then divide by `size_of::<u8>()`, which you'd have to do if you wrote this generically.

Comment: @PeterHall You also have to know the sizes of the types to know that `4` is the correct result, this just moves comments to code. If constant evaluation was further along, I'd move the `let` to a `const` and add a [`compile_error!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html) that asserts the value is `4`. I'd strongly advocate for *not*  writing this generically, so I wasn't as concerned about that case ;-)

Comment: I think you can write this generically, as long as you assume the output is &[u8], in which case you can dispense with the division, and just multiply by the `size_of` the source type.

Comment: @PeterHall well, depends on how generic you mean and what you expect the behavior to be. For example, if you allow an input `Vec<T>`, you allow a `Vec<&[(String, BTreeMap<char, f32>, PhantomData)]>` as well, which I wouldn't think would be a great idea.

Comment: @PeterHall if you want a more principled generic, something like the [safe-transmute crate](https://crates.io/crates/safe-transmute) might be more applicable.

Comment: What's wrong with that? You know.. if you wanted to turn a bunch of pointers to bytes... :P But you can obviously protect from that by using marker traits to opt-in useful types. It would look something like: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=736bf9be1c798d568f22471be7f677ff&version=stable

Comment: I didn't know about that crate! I'm sure there didn't used to be so many crates... ;)

Comment: The issue with `Layout` is not something I'd have suspected. In low-level code I'm used to worrying about casting to a pointer with *greater* alignment, but casting to a pointer with *lower* alignment has always been safe. I wonder if it should be specified that allocators should handle this case graciously.

Answer (score 7):

If in-place convert is not so mandatory, something like this manages [bytes order](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.2.2/byteorder) control and avoids the unsafe block:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::{WriteBytesExt, BigEndian};

fn main() {
    let vec32: Vec<u32> = vec![0xaabbccdd, 2];
    let mut vec8: Vec<u8> = vec![];

    for elem in vec32 {
        vec8.write_u32::<BigEndian>(elem).unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", vec8);
}
```

Comment: Would the compiler's optimization (with `-O3`) make the whole for-loop a no-op?

Answer (score 1):

Simply transmuting the Vec or using `from_raw_parts` is undefined behavior because the deallocation API [requires](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html#tymethod.deallocate) that the passed `Layout` is the same as the allocation was allocated with. To do this kind of conversion soundly you need to go through the Vec's associated allocator and call [shrink](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html#method.shrink) to convert the layout to the new alignment before calling `from_raw_parts`. This depends on the allocator being able to perform in-place reallocation.

If you don't need the resulting vector to be resizable then reinterpreting a `&mut [u32]` borrow of the vec to `&mut [u8]` would be a simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem using a bitshifting copy.

It works on my x64 machine, but I am unsure if I have made unsafe assumptions about little/big endianism.

Runtime performance would be faster if this cast could be done memory inplace  without the need for a copy, but I have not figured out how to do this yet.

````rust
/// Cast Vec<u32> to Vec<u8> without modifying underlying byte data
/// ```
/// # use fractals::services::vectors::vec_u32_to_u8;
/// assert_eq!( vec_u32_to_u8(&vec![ 0x12345678 ]), vec![ 0x12u8, 0x34u8, 0x56u8, 0x78u8 ]);
/// ```
#[allow(clippy::identity_op)]
pub fn vec_u32_to_u8(data: &Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u8> {
    // TODO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631065/how-to-convert-a-u32-array-to-a-u8-array-in-place
    // TODO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037033/how-to-slice-a-large-veci32-as-u8
    let capacity = 32/8 * data.len() as usize;  // 32/8 == 4
    let mut output = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(capacity);
    for &value in data {
        output.push((value >> 24) as u8);  // r
        output.push((value >> 16) as u8);  // g
        output.push((value >>  8) as u8);  // b
        output.push((value >>  0) as u8);  // a
    }
    output
}
````

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
let vec32: Vec<u32> = vec![1u32, 2u32];
let mut vec8: Vec<u8> = vec![];
for v in &vec32{
    for b in v.to_be_bytes(){
        vec8.push(b);
    }
}
println!("{:?}", vec32);
println!("{:?}", vec8);
```

[Playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=499001151556a707badce93aa544dc1c)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not in-place.